# SQL Stored procedure if (@variable = 0) doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've created a Stored procedure with some variables and a nested if statement.
When I call the Stored procedure from my program and check the returned dataset for the returned values, my dataset is empty while there should be records in it. After some testing I noticed when the statement if (@PoolID = 0) is tested and @PoolID is 0, it won't go trough the if statement... So whenever I set the variable poolid to 0 in my code I get the results from the else statement...

Anybody who knows what's going wrong?
Thx

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pool_select]

@PartnerCode nvarchar(8),
@GebrID int,
@PoolID int,
@Bevoegdheid int

AS

IF (@PoolID = 0)
BEGIN
    IF (@Bevoegdheid < 3)
    BEGIN
        SELECT
        p.*,
        pr.poolrecht
        FROM racpPool p, racpPoolrecht pr
        WHERE
        p.poolid = pr.poolid and
        p.PartnerCode = @PartnerCode and
        pr.poolrecht > 0 and
        p.actief = 1 and
        pr.GebrID = @GebrID
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN   
        SELECT *
        FROM racpPool p
        WHERE standaardpool = 1
        and partnercode = @PartnerCode
    END     
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    IF (@Bevoegdheid < 3)
    BEGIN
        SELECT
        p.*,
        pr.poolrecht
        FROM racpPool p, racpPoolrecht pr
        WHERE 
        p.poolid = pr.poolid and
        p.PartnerCode = @PartnerCode and
        pr.poolrecht > 0 and
        p.actief = 1 and
        pr.GebrID = @GebrID and 
        p.PoolID = @PoolID
    END
    ELSE IF (@Bevoegdheid >= 3)
    BEGIN   
        SELECT *
        FROM racpPool p
        WHERE PoolID = @PoolID
    END 
END
```

Comment: Are you sure @PoolID is zero?  If you run it in SSMS do you get the results you expect?

Comment: Are you sure about your other variables too?  In the `ELSE` you don't do filtering on `@Partnercode` but you do in the upper `IF`...

Comment: Have you tried running SQL Server Profiler to see what is actually being sent in to the procedure?

Comment: When I test the stored procedure in SQL mamangement studio the stored procedure gives me records when I set poolID to 0. I also changed my stored procedure, but when I pass PoolID as 0, it goed through the statement if (@PoolID > 0), so it's never 0. I don't get it why. I also checked my parameters I pass and it says PoolID = 0.

Comment: @Ben are you sure your running on the same database?

Comment: @Ben - remark out the queries in the `IF..ELSE` statements, put in some `PRINT` statements like `PRINT '@PoolID evaluated to 0'`, and start there.  I suspect it's evaluating correctly but you are getting unexpected results from the queries.

Comment: Can you please post how you are calling this sp? I suspect the problem is where you set your PoolId variable from the calling code.

Comment: What behavior do you want if PoolID is null? Consider that you may be inadvertently sending a null value and that perhaps you can just add some null handling code.

Comment: a side issue, but were you aware that using IF/ELSE statements in stored procs means that only the first chosen branch is compiled and stored while other branches aren't? Consider making each branch it's own proc too, which will also help with testing.

Comment: @Iain - That isn't true. Try `create proc #foo AS IF DATEPART(S,GETDATE())<30 SELECT * FROM sys.types ELSE SELECT * FROM sys.tables; GO ; EXEC #foo; GO ; SELECT query_plan FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cross apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) WHERE objectid=object_id('tempdb..#foo')`

Comment: First, try setting default value as 0 and passing NULL from code. See what happens.

Also try to confirm if you're actually sending 0, using SQL Server profiler or fiddler.

Comment: @Martin - SQL Server allows only one execution plan per stored procedure. See http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/if-statements-and-stored-procedure-performance.aspx

Comment: @Iain - Did you even try the code in my comment? That article is from 2004. Probably applied to SQL Server 2000!

Comment: @Martin - nope, no instance available here but there is a full discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510489/t-f-using-if-statements-in-a-procedure-produces-multiple-plans with good explanations to support you. Since 2005 those branches may get plans, but they still don't make testing easier - and leave all the conditionals in the app where they belong anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite it as one single select of 4-part UNION ALL.

I also notice that your conditions are not comprehensive, not sure if that is intentional.

In the 2nd branch of `@PoolID = 0` , the tests are specifically `@Bevoegdheid < 3` and `@Bevoegdheid >= 3` (instead of ELSE ) which will do nothing if `@Bevoegdheid IS NULL`

The optimizer will only run the branch that fits the criteria marked with  <<<

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pool_select]
@PartnerCode nvarchar(8),
@GebrID int,
@PoolID int,
@Bevoegdheid int
-- WITH RECOMPILE -- << may need this

AS

    SELECT
    p.*,
    pr.poolrecht
    FROM racpPool p, racpPoolrecht pr
    WHERE
    p.poolid = pr.poolid and
    p.PartnerCode = @PartnerCode and
    pr.poolrecht > 0 and
    p.actief = 1 and
    pr.GebrID = @GebrID
    AND @PoolID = 0 and @Bevoegdheid < 3   --- <<<
UNION ALL
    SELECT *, NULL
    FROM racpPool p
    WHERE standaardpool = 1
    and partnercode = @PartnerCode
    AND @PoolID = 0 and IsNull(@Bevoegdheid,4) >= 3 --- <<<
UNION ALL
    SELECT
    p.*,
    pr.poolrecht
    FROM racpPool p, racpPoolrecht pr
    WHERE 
    p.poolid = pr.poolid and
    p.PartnerCode = @PartnerCode and
    pr.poolrecht > 0 and
    p.actief = 1 and
    pr.GebrID = @GebrID and 
    p.PoolID = @PoolID
    AND Isnull(@PoolID,-1) <> 0 AND @Bevoegdheid < 3   --- <<<
UNION ALL
    SELECT *, NULL
    FROM racpPool p
    WHERE PoolID = @PoolID
    AND Isnull(@PoolID,-1) <> 0 AND @Bevoegdheid >= 3  --- <<<
```

Comment: Thx for your code which is better than mine. My problem was that I didn't pass my variables in the same order as my variables in the stored procedure. Really weird...